# How to connect a home network camera to an Amazon EC2 instance?

Tags: router, vpn, camera, cloud

I have a network camera in my home that I want to monitor from a software running on an Amazon EC2 instance.

The home network have a dynamically assigned public IP address. My router is an Ubee and I have access to the router configuration. I also have a DNS name for my public IP (updated periodically).

Also I have an Amazon EC2 instance.

What is the best way to connect the remote software to my camera? Can I achieve this by setting up a VPN, and what configuration for that should I use?

The best option would be to set some VPN software (server) on my local computer, which is also connected to the same network, as my router often resets itself. The second option would be to set up the router.

The third option would be to simply use port forwarding, but that is the least desirable as it will expose my camera to the public network.

Comment: I use your "best option" here. Cisco RV325 VPN router for access to my home network from a remote location. My external IP address only changes every year or so and I can manage that. The Cisco router does not reset itself.

Comment: Your best option is the way to go. You don't need a VPN router like John said, just set up OpenVPN in your local computer.